# Can I show that this sequence is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)$,$(b_n)$ be real sequences with the following properties:

$$ a_n \to 0 \hspace{0.2cm} \text{as} \hspace{0.2cm} n\to \infty$$

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n b_k  \hspace{0.2cm} \text{is a bounded sequence}$$

**Question**: Can I show that  $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k$ is a bounded sequence?

Comment: what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @jimjim Well I thought about applying the triangle inequality but this would require to show that $(b_n)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

No. One counterexample is
$$
a_k = \begin{cases}
1/\sqrt k, &\text{if $k$ is even}, \\
0, &\text{if $k$ is odd};
\end{cases}
\qquad
b_k = (-1)^kk.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I edited my question. I want to show that the sequence is bounded now, not null.

Comment: If I understand correctly the sequence $(a_n b_n)$ is $0,\sqrt{2},0,\sqrt{4}, 0, \sqrt{6},0,\dots$. Hence the sequence $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k$ contains $\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{2k}$ as a subsequence, and this subsequence is bounded below by $1/\sqrt{2}$. But it is not clear to me if this sequence is bounded above.

Comment: It's certainly not bounded above (consider the terms $\frac n2\le k\le n$ for instance), which is why it's a counterexample.

Comment: I see that each of these $n/2+1$ terms is at least $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$. Hence each term of the subsequence is at least $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\to \infty$. Is this correct?